# Почему тут не нужен закрывающий тег

Tags: html

```
<p>
<ul>
    <li>
        Всегда потеплее одевайтесь и защищайте свои головы
        и тело с помощью html.
    </li>
    <li>
        Как можно больше отдыхайте, пока здесь находитесь. Сон помогает
        усвоить все эти правила.
    </li>
    <li>
        Не упустите возможность посмотреть работы наших местных художников
        в бизнес-центре галерее CSS
    </li>

</ul>
<p>
    У вас возникли какие-то вопросы? Вы всегда можете найти ответы в
    <a href="http://www.headfirstlabs.com"><em>Лабы Хеадферс</em></a>
    Вопросы все еще остались ? Расслабьтесь, Вебвиль - это достаточно гостепримный
    город. Просто попросите кого-нибудь вам помочб. И, как здесь приятно говорить:
</p>
```

Я открыл `<p>`, вложил туда `<ul>`, а чекер показывает, что закрывать `<p>` не надо, мол, и так все ок. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Полный исходник https://pastebin.com/c6bigeHG

Comment: Так закрой , что за чекер?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: у тебя `<p>` перед `<ul>` не закрыт

Comment: прикол в том, что <ul> и не надо было в <p> походу..

Comment: вроде бы разобрался

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете вложить список внутри абзаца.

`<p>` может иметь только строчные элементы в виде дочерних элементов и без элементов блока (см., Например, в [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/p)). `<ul>` же является блочным элементом([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul))!

Причина, по которой браузер интерпретирует ваш код, находится в спецификации разбора HTML5. Спецификация описывает пример, очень похожий на ваш собственный: [whatwg link](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

Answer (score 2):

Тег `<p>` закрывать [необязательно](http://htmlbook.ru/html/p).

Если закрывающего тега нет, считается, что конец абзаца совпадает с началом следующего блочного элемента, в вашем случае `<ul>`, а так как у вас потом ещё есть закрывающий тег `</p>`, то возникает ошибка парсинга.